# Prove that $A + B$ is a subspace of $C$

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ and $B$ are subspaces of a vector space $C$, how can I show that $A+B$ is also a subset of $C$ if $A + B = \{a + b \mid a\in A, b\in B\}$?

Comment: A subspace is a subset which satisfies three conditions. Do you know these three conditions? Have you tried to verify any of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same old, show that they are contained in there over addition and scalar multiplication
let $a,c\in A$ and $b,d\in B$ be given, then
$$(a+b)+(c+d)=(a+c)+(b+d)$$
as we have $a+c\in A$ and $b+d\in B$ we clearly have it closed under addition and for scalar

$$k(a+b)=ka+kb$$
and again, we have $ka\in A$ and $kb \in B$

Answer (score 0):

You need to show that each property of subspaces is satisfied by $A+B$.

For instance, to show that $A+B$ is closed under scalar multiplication, fix $x\in A+B$ and a scalar $\lambda$. Then since $x\in A+B$, we have $x=a+b$ for some $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. Then $$\lambda x=\lambda(a+b)=\lambda a+\lambda b.$$ Since $A$ and $B$ are subspaces, $\lambda a\in A$ and $\lambda b\in B$ - so $\lambda x\in A+B$.

You should be able to verify the others on your own, similarly.